# Heroku create-react-app deploy Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: reactjs, typescript, heroku, create-react-app

Whenever I deploy my heroku app with the create-react-app buildpack, the first time I try to access my domain, the page loaded is white and there is an error in the developer console saying

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

in the file `main.6396d38a.js:1` which is generated by the react build. However, when I refresh the page, the website works perfectly fine. Is there a reason this could be happening? I tried to replicate the error on my `localhost` using `npm run build`, and `serve -s build` but my website works perfectly fine there. Why would this only show up once after every react deploy to heroku?

My package.json has a homepage associated with the domain name of my website (not .herokuapp.com)

`"homepage": "https://www.example.com/"`

Comment: Could this be cache issue or potentially it's loading additional chunk?

Comment: I don't think it's a cache issue because I can replicate the error across different browsers. What do you mean by an additional chunk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your `package.json` make sure your `homepage` URL is correct:

```
"homepage": "https://app.herokuapp.com/"
```

---

## Update

Further investigation shows this was a caching issue. Clearing cookies, website content, and DNS fixed the issue.

Comment: @JohnDoe Have you tried the `type="text/babel"` on script tag trick?

Comment: It's in the question - on line 1 of `main.6396d38a.js`

Comment: Yes I mean the line of code. Quick question. What version react-scripts are you using and is it using babel or JSTransform? Do you use JSX?

Comment: The files are minified in the build, so the line of code isn't really significant. I am using version 3.1.0 of react-scripts-ts and it is using babel.

Comment: Are you using TSX ?

Comment: Yes, I am using TSX

Comment: Do you only use Tsx or are you mixing Jsx? I'm trying to narrow down if it's webpack issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198845/discussion-between-johndoe-and-riddell).

Comment: @JohnDoe Glad, you sorted the issue.

Comment: Same caching issue happened to me. Force reloading by Cmd+shift+r on the production URL fixed the problem.