# Default react project - ERROR BY SETTING HOMEPAGE- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', i've read many answers none work

Tags: reactjs, production, serve

I'm only trying make a production build from the default react project and just by setting the homepage field in the package.json, when i run "serve -s build" on my local machine i get that error. I was getting this error in my main project, that it will run on a personal machine with nginx using reverse proxy, thats why i'm trying to make it work on the default project, to see where i can fix this. The Project runs with this field with the "npm start". I've tried most of the solutions presented in those links below and none of them work for me:

[Create-React-App build - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340240/create-react-app-build-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

[React/Node Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222722/react-node-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/527

[Heroku create-react-app deploy Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762536/heroku-create-react-app-deploy-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

https://community.netlify.com/t/react-application-builds-deploys-into-a-blank-page/2571

-Remove homepage is not a option
-Homepage field it is not incorrect since its only : "homepage" : "test" for testing in the same machine
-One of the answers suggest to edit all the source code, but i think this is not a option
-Tried to put this in the index.html "" and ""
-Most of the requests gets the status code of 304
-Putting this to the homepage field does not work too "./test"
-Sometimes i do get this error too : "Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error."
-Tried to clear cache and cookies

Anything else that i can try?
Many thanks to anyone that can help me on this!